# AVAudioUnitEQ / .BandPass filter doesn't work

Tags: cocoa-touch, swift, avfoundation, ios8

I can't get the `AVAudioUnitEQ` to work.

Here's a piece of code that should filter out everything except 659.255Hz +/-0.05 octaves:

```
// Create Audio Engine

var audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()

// Create Equalizer Node

var equalizerNode = AVAudioUnitEQ(numberOfBands: 1) 
var epualizerParameters: AVAudioUnitEQFilterParameters = equalizerNode.bands.first as AVAudioUnitEQFilterParameters
epualizerParameters.filterType = .BandPass
epualizerParameters.frequency = 659.255
epualizerParameters.bandwidth = 0.05
epualizerParameters.bypass = false
audioEngine.attachNode(equalizerNode)

// Configure Audio Engine

var format = audioEngine.inputNode.inputFormatForBus(0)
audioEngine.connect(audioEngine.inputNode, to: equalizerNode, format: format)
audioEngine.connect(equalizerNode, to: audioEngine.outputNode, format: format)


// Start Audio Engine

var error:NSError?
audioEngine.startAndReturnError(&error)
```

However, when I run it, put on my headphones and sing into the microphone, I can hear myself loud and clear.

Now, according to Wikipedia, the Band Pass filter is:

> ... a device that passes frequencies within a certain range and
>   rejects (attenuates) frequencies outside that range.

What am I doing wrong? I want to filter out everything except given frequency range.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @BhavinVaghela I do not even remember ever having this problem. 7 years ago. :)

Comment: Okay no problem :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was your EQ params.

I created a [github project](https://github.com/genedelisa/InputBandpass.git) with sliders and switches. You can hear the difference.
Try it.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I've just tried it. 1) In the iOS Simulator, all I get is silence; 2) On the iPhone with headphones, when I turn on the EQ, I get `AUSetFormat: error -10868` on `inputFormatForBus(0)` line; 3) On the iPhone without headphones I can hear myself without filtering (with `bypass` is set to `NO`). Any ideas?

Comment: This looks like a bug in the SDK. I've tried to search for `AUSetFormat: error -10868` with absolutely no success. The Audio Engine crashes every time I plug the headphones (into my iPhone 4S). I was planning to address this later when the filtering works, but nope. Sigh.

Comment: I tried my project just in the simulator and I hear it working OK. I haven't tried it on my iPhone because I don't have iOS 8 on it. When you say "I've just tried it", does "it" mean my project?

Comment: Yeah, I mean the project. Now, this is weird.

Comment: I'm using XCode6 beta 7 on OSX 10.9.4. How about you? Try doing a git pull, clean the project, put on headphones, run it and say "work, damnit" and see what happens.

Comment: Even though it doesn't work for me, I'm awarding this answer +50 for all the effort. Thank you!

Comment: "Page not found" for this link.

Answer (score 1):

This works in my project which uses a playerNode.

```
var format =  engine.mainMixerNode.outputFormatForBus(0)
engine.connect(playerNode, to: EQNode, format: format )
engine.connect(EQNode, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: format)
```

I see you're using the engine's inputNode. Try swapping out these few lines (hook into the mixer instead of the outputNode) and let us know if it works.

Comment: Try a larger value for bandwidth and see if you hear anything

Comment: Tried it. Still the same.