# Implement equalizer for audio streaming IOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, streaming, core-audio

How to Implement equalizer for audio streaming IOS application. We have already implemented audio streaming application on IOS SDK. We need to create equalizer with audio streaming. Please share your ideas.

Answer (score 1):

New in `iOS9` you can feed a `AVAudioCompressedBuffer` which might be useful for you or if you need to target `iOS8` you could use `AVAudioPCMBuffer`.

Once you have the stream in a buffer, you could use `AVAudioEngine` and connect the input to an `AVAudioUnitEQ` node.

For examples, look at:
[AVAudioUnitEQ / .BandPass filter doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25688556/avaudiouniteq-bandpass-filter-doesnt-work)

[Tap Mic Input Using AVAudioEngine in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203622/tap-mic-input-using-avaudioengine-in-swift)

[Stream data from network in AVAudioEngine, is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30862664/stream-data-from-network-in-avaudioengine-is-it-possible)

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#502